# Passing a variable value to a macro

Tags: assembly, macros

If i have a macro named, for example, test, and i want to pass a variable value to it, how should i do it?
For example:

```
test macro num
    ; ...
endm
```

and i call it like this:

```
test num
```

and num is defined in data segment as a db for example.
My question is, is that possible? Why do i get an error when i do this? and do i even need to do this? cant i just access `num` inside the macro without passing it as argument?

Regardless, thanks.

EDIT 1: here is a sample of the actuall code:

```
    ;... in the data segment i have car_fich defined like this
    car_fich    db    9
    ; ........................................................

fill_array macro car_fich
    mov ah, car_fich
    ; .. do other things
endm

Main proc

    fill_array car_fich

Main endp
```

Comment: What assembler are you referring to? You may have a name clash between your `MACRO` name "test" and the [`test`](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/TEST.html) instruction.

Comment: @zx485 the name test was just an example for me to explain my question, not the actuall code

Comment: So what does the actual code look like? [mcve]?

Comment: @zx485 ill edit the question with a sample of the actuall code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still guess that you have a name clash between `car_fich` from the data segment and `car_fich` from the macro definition. Why do you both name the same?

Some assemblers use the latest definition of a symbol as current (This is *fundamentally different* from the use of [scope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)) in higher level languages).

So in this case the definition in the macro would override the definition in the data segment essentially making the latter invisible and hence creating an error(most likely; thank the assembler that it is, because otherwise it would be even harder to debug).

If this is the case can be checked by changing the symbol in the macro:

```
    ;... in the data segment i have car_fich defined like this
    car_fich    db    9
    ; ........................................................

fill_array macro m_car_fich        ; changed symbol name
    mov ah, m_car_fich             ; changed symbol name
    ; .. do other things
endm

Main proc

    fill_array car_fich            ; refers to data segment variable

Main endp
```

Comment: do i need to have m_car_fich defined in the data segment?

Comment: @jeyejow: No. Your problem seems to be that you confuse the variable definition in the data segment and the parameter definition in the MACRO. Both are symbols, so they should (ideally) be unique. In this example you pass the symbol `car_fich` to the MACRO symbol `m_car_fich`. `car_fich` is treated as parameter in the MACRO - and this parameter's name is `m_car_fich` in the scope of the MACRO. They _shouldn't_  have the same symbol/name, because they do not mean the same.

Comment: ohhok, im pretty new to assembly, maybe i should read the definitions agains, im going to test it with that fix, if it works ill accept your awnser

Comment: one more question, can i call other variable from inside the macro that arent passed to it? for example if i have other variable in datasegment called var, can i inside the macro say something like mov ah, var ? or do i need to pass it to the macro so i can use the value?

Comment: @jeyejow: Yes you can! But be careful with global variables (as in most programming languages). Sometimes it would defeat the use of a MACRO. So you can use a GLOBAL variable named `var` defined in the data segment in the MACRO if you don't have a second definition like in `test MACRO var` which would make `var` a LOCAL variable and not a GLOBAL anymore.

Comment: oh ok, appreciated!

Comment: @jeyejow: One more thing. Make yourself familiar with [the scope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)) of symbols/variables. This is not only useful for assembler, but for all programming languages.